# Without resorting to induction show that $L_n^2=L_{n+1}L_{n-1}+5(-1)^n$,Where $L_n$ is $n^{th}$ Lucas number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

> Without resorting to induction show that
>   **$L_n^2=L_{n+1}L_{n-1}+5(-1)^n$,Where $L_n$ is $n^{th}$ Lucas number.**

By definition of Lucas number $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}\implies L_{n-1}=L_n-L_{n-2}$ and $L_{n+1}=L_{n}+L_{n-2}.$

Now,$L_{n+1}L_{n-1}=L_n^2+L_{n}L_{n-1}-L_{n}L_{n-2}-L_{n-2}L_{n-1}$

From,here i'm not getting how to proceed further...

Comment: You can certainly use the explicit definition of Lucas number, multiply out the terms and show equivalence that way, but it seems like a pain in the ass. Also, your expression $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n+1}$ is wrong; it should be either $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$ or $L_n=L_{n+1}-L_{n-1}$. Did you possibly mean $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:Upto now i have'nt proved $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$,so ethically we cannot use this result.

Comment: Hint: $\begin{bmatrix}L_{n+2} & L_{n+1}\\ L_{n+1} & L_n \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}L_{n+1} & L_n\\ L_n & L_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1):

The identity
$$
L_n^2=L_{n+1}L_{n-1}+5(-1)^n
$$
for the Lucas numbers seems to be closed related to [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Cassini_and_Catalan's_identities) for the Fibonacci numbers:
$$
F_n^2 - F_{n+1}F_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}
$$
which follows from taking determinants in
$$
\begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^n
$$

Indeed, the identity in question has a closely related proof:
it follows from taking determinants in
$$
\begin{pmatrix}L_{n+1}&L_n\\L_n&L_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}L_{2}&L_1\\L_1&L_{0}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}3&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The problem is: how do you prove *without induction* the matrix identity?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Binet [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasNumber.html),  $$L_n=a^n+b^n$$ where $a,b$ are the roots of $$t^2-t-1=0$$

$\implies ab=-1, a+b=1\implies a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=?$

$$\implies L_n^2-L_{n-1}L_{n+1}$$

$$=(a^n+b^n)^2-(a^{n+1}+b^{n+1})(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$$

$$=2(ab)^n-(ab)^{n-1}(a^2+b^2)=?$$